# Passing a generator as callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, redux, generator, es6-promise, redux-saga

In my redux-saga function, I need to yield a put in a callback. So I am passing a generator as a callback. But my callback is not executing. If instead, I use an anonymous function then the callback runs.

This logs data:

```
  Tabletop.init({
    key: action.key,
    callback: googleData => {
      console.log(googleData);
    },
    simpleSheet: true
  });
```

This does not log the data:

```
  Tabletop.init({
    key: action.key,
    callback: yield function*(googleData) {
      console.log(googleData);
      yield put(setProblems(googleData));
    },
    simpleSheet: true
  });
```

I saw online that you can yield in then part of a promise. Tabletop.js supports promises like this:

```
function init() {
  Tabletop.init( {
    key: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE/pubhtml',
    simpleSheet: true }
  ).then(function(data, tabletop) { 
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

But this way is not working for me as I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...}).then(function (data, tab...')

[ https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop/issues/175 ]

Can someone tell me the right way to get this to work? Once I fetch the data I want to set it in my reducer.

Comment: What version of `Tabletop` are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.5.2. I guess that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I made it work. Do let me know if there is any other way to make this work.

I created a function that returned  a promise:

```
function fetchProblemsPromise(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Tabletop.init({
      key: key,
      callback: googleData => {
        resolve(googleData);
      },
      simpleSheet: true
    });
  });
}
```

And then yielded it:

```
const data = yield call(fetchProblemsPromise, [action.key]);
yield put(setProblems(data));
```

This helped me figure it out:
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/508